# Different Android and iOS app version

Tags: android, ios, cordova, build, versioning

Good day,

Previously I had an issue on my iOS app only so I incremented the PATCH part of my version in config.xml, say from 1.1.19 to 1.1.20 while my Android app is still at 1.1.19.

Now I have both updates for both apps. My questions are:

1. If possible, can I set a different version for iOS and Android i.e. iOS would now be 1.1.21 while the Android app would be at 1.1.20?
2. If #1 is not possible, would it still be best practice to let the Android app version skip 1.1.20 and go to 1.1.21 so they will be in the same version with the iOS app?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

If possible, can I set a different version for iOS and Android i.e. iOS would now be 1.1.21 while the Android app would be at 1.1.20?I assume you are using cordova or something like this. Answer below

If #1 is not possible, would it still be best practice to let the Android app version skip 1.1.20 and go to 1.1.21 so they will be in the same version with the iOS app?
skip 1.1.20 and go to 1.1.21

Then you have both versions on the same level

Comment: Thanks for you response and I just went for this route for now.

Answer (score 1):

In the config.xml, you can use `version` for Android version and `ios-CFBundleVersion` for iOS version, so you can use different version numbers for each platform.

`<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.1.20" ios-CFBundleVersion="1.1.21" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
</widget>`

Comment: Thanks for your response! Wow! I didn't assume that can be done that way but currently I already just skipped one patch version for Android. I would also like to confirm if skipping a patch version is alright in mobile app deployments which is from my second question?

Comment: Best practice is to not to skip versions, but I don't think users will ever notice or bother about that.

Comment: Got it. I tried this and it seems to work 50% because on iOS, with this configuration, the CFBundleShortVersionString will be set to "1.1.20" which is not supposed to be. I have no choice but to proceed with the version skip for Android :(

Comment: Yeah, version will still set `CFBundleShortVersionString`. `CFBundleShortVersionString` is the build version, not the app version. That's is something internal for you. But would be good if they matched

Comment: I agree! Hoping to be able to set these kinds of configurations in the future. Thank you for you help in this!